How to auto sync connected Sharepoint list to your tableau data source
How to auto sync SharePoint list data to tableau data source.
Tableau Report has already connected to SharePoint List using JDBC via Tableau Online, however when user added new data in SharePoint List it can't auto sync in tableau data source.
